# Getting a Python command-line argument using "getopt" when there is no corresponding key

Tags: python, getopt

I'm writing a python program where I need to read various optional command-line arguments, and one REQUIRED argument (a string) that ideally would be the last argument on the command-line.  When using `getopt`, I can read-in everything except this string unless I set it up to also require the use of a flag (let's say `-s`) preceding it, like this:

```
Usage: myProgram.py [options] -s "some string"

Options available:
    -x                                     # Turn on option X
    -y                                     # Turn on option Y
    -a "used-defined parameter 1"
    -b "used-defined parameter 2"
    -c "used-defined parameter 3"
    -d "used-defined parameter 4"
    -s "used-defined string" (REQUIRED)
```

where the code to process the arguments would be as follows:

```
    (opts, args) = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], 'xya:b:c:d:s:')
```

This will parse the arguments into the key-value pairs of the allowed command-line options.

Instead, I'd like to allow the user to enter it like this:

```
Usage: myProgram.py [options] "some string"
```

without the `-s` identifier.  As it's written above, if the `-s` is not explicitly included, the `getopt` code won't capture that last string.  I can't simply assume `mystring = sys.argv[-1]` because it could be a parameter for one of the other optional arguments.  How should I modify the getopt line (or what extra step should I add) to capture that last string when there is no key to identify it, while not confusing it with another existing key?

Comment: Are you open to using `argparse` instead? It supports this kind of thing much better.

Comment: @gmds - I would prefer not having to rewrite the entire command-line parsing code, especially since this is the only piece that doesn't work the way I want it to (the rest works just fine).

Comment: Using an "option" for something which isn't *optional* is paradoxical. Just pick it up from `args`.

Comment: @tripleee - That isn't at all helpful, and it completely misses the most significant point: how the capture that string **_while not confusing it with the value for another existing key_**.

Comment: I don't think *I'm* confused. If you want to be able to say `-s` with or without an argument, that's a problem; but having option and non-option arguments is completely trivial.

Comment: Demo: https://ideone.com/Vz1wd6

Comment: @tripleee - Ok, thanks for the example; I was eventually able to figure out what you were talking about.  The issue was that you really didn't explain what you meant by _"picking it up from `args`"_, and your second response made it sound like you **_really_** didn't understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution (*as suggested by @tripleee*) was to add a couple of additional lines to capture the remaining command-line arguments and assign them to the variable I needed to use in the code.  Specifically:

```
    (opts, args) = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], 'xya:b:c:d:')
    if args != "":
        if len(args) == 1:
            myString = args[0]
        else:
            myString = " ".join(args)
```